# resetting fields with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to reset fields (selects and textboxes) in a partial. Here is what I have so far:

```
var $inputs = $('#StudentTable :select');
$inputs.each(function () { 
  if ($(this).name = "TeachingAsstSelect") { 
    $('select[name="TeachingAsstSelect"]').each(function () { 
      $(this).text(""); 
    }) 
  } 
  else { 
    $(this).val("Select");
  } 
});
```

Here "TeachingAsstSelect" is being cleared, but other selects are not reset. Am I missing something? More importantly, Am I doing it the right way?

Comment: It would be very useful for us to see your html as well. Maybe you could publish relevant parts on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to test equality of a string, you should use `==` or `===`. See here form more on that: [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Also, as @Raminson suggests, try use the `attr()` method instead.

```
if ($(this).attr('name') == "TeachingAsstSelect") {
```

Or better yet, nesting `.each()` twice like that may not perform as well as other solutions.

I also notice that you are testing name in your `if` condition then using a jquery selector to match again on `[name="TeachingAsstSelect"]`.  What about simplifying like this:

```
var $teachingAsstInputs = $('#StudentTable :select[name="TeachingAsstSelect"]');
$($teachingAsstInputs).text(""); 

var $otherInputs = $('#StudentTable :select').not('[name="TeachingAsstSelect"]');
$($otherInputs).val("Select");
```

Answer (score 1):

For jQuery objects you should use `attr()` method, `name` is one of the DOM Element properties.

Change this:

```
  if ($(this).name = "TeachingAsstSelect") {
```

to:

```
  if ($(this).attr('name') == "TeachingAsstSelect") {
```

also note that for comparison you should use  `==` operator, currently you are setting the value.